# In cassandra 0.8.2 sstableleader how to use -i or --ignore option?

Tags: linux, cassandra, command, loader

I am trying to load **sstable** with **cassandra** utility **sstableloader**
But they suggested running this with the **-i** or **--ignore** option to avoid some nodes.
While trying this option, I am getting a **too many arguments error**; has anybody tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug ([CASSANDRA-3247](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3247)), sorry. It will be fixed for the 0.8.7 release and the upcoming 1.0.

Comment: Thanks bro, spent lot of time to figure it all.